# YARA Rule - Regex - String with at least one digit

Tags: regex, yara

I'm new to YARA rules and I wanted to build something really simple, a regex to match a hostname naming convention in my company.
Something like:
`/AX[BCD][EFG](?=.*\d)[A-Z0-9]{5}/`
where the last five characters HAVE TO have at least one digit.
Is there a way to "translate" this to YARA? Keeping in mind that only basic constructs are supported:

- Alternation (|)
- Concatenation
- Repetition (*, *?, +, +?, ?, ??, {digit*,digit*}, {digit*,digit*}?, {digit+})
- Boundaries (\b, \B, ^, $)
- Grouping ((, ))
- Character classes (., \w, \W, \s, \S, \d, \D, [...], [^...])
- Hex escapes (\xHH)
- Normal escapes (\ + any special character)
- Anything else is a literal or illegal

Thanks!

Comment: Do URLs always have the same length, so the length doesn't need to be checked?

Comment: Unfortunately the length needs to be checked. It has to be exactly 9 characters with the last 5 containing at lest one digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the pattern with a grouping and alternation matching 5 characters checking for a digit on every position.

```
AX[BCD][EFG](\d[A-Z\d]{4}|[A-Z\d]\d[A-Z\d]{3}|[A-Z\d]{2}\d[A-Z\d]{2}|[A-Z\d]{3}\d[A-Z\d]|[A-Z\d]{4}\d)
```

If you don't want a partial match but match 9 characters in total, you can append anchors around the pattern:

```
^AX[BCD][EFG](\d[A-Z\d]{4}|[A-Z\d]\d[A-Z\d]{3}|[A-Z\d]{2}\d[A-Z\d]{2}|[A-Z\d]{3}\d[A-Z\d]|[A-Z\d]{4}\d)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LWGq3n/1)

Comment: Thank you so much! The first pattern works like a charm. On top of that if you need more than 5 characters, for example 10 than the patter will look like: AX[BCD][EFG](\d[A-Z\d]{9}|[A-Z\d]\d[A-Z\d]{8}|[A-Z\d]{2}\d[A-Z\d]{7}|[A-Z\d]{3}\d[A-Z\d]{6}|[A-Z\d]{4}\d[A-Z\d]{5}|[A-Z\d]{5}\d[A-Z\d]{4}|[A-Z\d]{6}\d[A-Z\d]{3}|[A-Z\d]{7}\d[A-Z\d]{2}|[A-Z\d]{8}\d[A-Z\d]|[A-Z\d]{9}\d)

Comment: @BeQuietAndDrive You are welcome, glad that it worked out. If the answer helped solving the question, feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If length is known to be correct (that is the regex doesn't need to assert length):

```
/AX[BCD][EFG][A-Z\d]*\d[A-Z\d]*
```

Comment: Unfortunately the length needs to be checked. It has to be exactly 9 characters with the last 5 containing at lest one digit.